# Script to send mail once a day for all failed ssh attempts

Tags: bash, ssh

This is my first question here. I am new to bash scripting. I have one server and I am looking for a means to notify for all failed ssh attempts and send me a mail once a day. I am using Centos 6.3.

I was looking to write a script to automatically send a mail at midnight with all failed attempts for the day. For this I think I need to set a cron job. That part is clear. As far as the bah script is concerned, my script is as follows:

```
chkssh(){

        thismonth=$(date | awk {'print $2'})
        thisdate=$(date | awk {'print $3'})
        today=$thismonth" "$thisdate

        cat /var/log/secure | grep ssh | grep Failed | grep "$today" | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' | sort -n  > /usr/local/temp/tempssh.txt
        prev_ip=$(cat /usr/local/temp/tempssh.txt| head -1)
        count=0
        while read this_ip
        do
                if [ $prev_ip == $this_ip ];then
                        count=$((count+1))
                        prev_ip=$this_ip
                else
                        echo "$count failed attempts from $prev_ip" >> /usr/local/temp/todayssh.txt
                        count=1
                        prev_ip=$this_ip
                fi

        done < /usr/local/temp/tempssh.txt
        rm -rf /usr/local/temp/tempssh.txt
        mail -r Monitor@mytestname.com -s "Daily Failed SSH reports"  me@mytestname.com </usr/local/temp/todayssh.txt
```

This seems to be sending all but the last ip which attempted to ssh into the server. For example, if there were 3 ips and 2 attempts each, my output shows on the first 2 and the last one is always skipped. Any ideas on what I am missing out on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you use something like fail2ban?

Comment: You should consider double-quoting those _ip variables. if they ever get set to empty, you could have some unexpected results.

Comment: @mateor - Do I include the $ within the quotes? i.e "$prev_ip" or $"prev_ip"?

Comment: @rahuL: You've already quoted several variables and did it right (no, there is no syntax where `$` would be followed by `"`).

Comment: alternatively http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/files/ instead of fail2ban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have the answer. Your last IP and its associated count is retained by its variables when it exits from the loop but those values are not written into your `todayssh.txt` file (since the loop was exited). Try adding a statement after the exit of the loop to write $prev_ip and $count again into the todayssh.txt file - I think that should give you the last IP and its count.

```
while read this_ip
        do
                if [ $prev_ip == $this_ip ];then
                        count=$((count+1))
                        prev_ip=$this_ip
                else
                        echo "$count failed attempts from $prev_ip" >> /usr/local/temp/todayssh.txt
                        count=1
                        prev_ip=$this_ip
                fi

        done < /usr/local/temp/tempssh.txt
        echo "$count failed attempts from $prev_ip" >> /usr/local/temp/todayssh.txt
```

Then mail it to yourself using the mail command and see if it works.

Hope this helps...